# running flask-migrate on a production environment: no ssh

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm running a python app on lambda with RDS. I would like to use flask-migrate but every example is a command line invocation.

So, my question: is it possible to run flask-migration on a lambda instance, either whenever the app starts or through a non-command line invocation?

Or I really need to open the RDS instance to the internet for the migration (and run from my local).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two options, without involving exposing your database on a public IP address:

1. Run the `flask db upgrade` command on a container or EC2 that is on the same VPC as your RDS database.
2. Run the `upgrade()` function programmatically in your lambda function:

```py
from flask_migrate import upgrade

app = ...
db = ...
migrate = ...

upgrade()
```